# Create div Using Array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of strings, I want to show each array element in its own `<div>` tag like
`<div "class">one</div><div class"two">one</div>` and each `div` tag should have a class that is common for all. All process start on click button

BUTTON CODE

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="abc();" runat="server" />
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION

```
function abc()
    {
        debugger;
        var arrayVariable = "one,two,three";
        var arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
        var temp;
        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.className = 'results';
            temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i];
            $('#inputcomshow').append(temp);
            //document.getElementById("#inputcomshow").value = replaced
        }

        }
```

Comment: Just stating what you want or need, is not a proper question for this site. You need to describe to us what specifically you are having trouble with. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Arrays are defined using []. So define your array var arrayVariable =[ 'one','two','three'];

Comment: @sudhir ojha i admitted array formate is [ 'one','two','three'] ok but i am getting the same problem

Comment: @CBroe i wand to show these elements like one,two,three show in <div class="classname"><div class="a">one<div><div class="a">two<div><div> formate

Comment: Did I not just tell you, that “I want” only is _not_ a proper problem description? Then why are you repeating it? Make an actual effort to explain what your _problem_ is now please.

Comment: @CBroe no one *has* to do as you tell them, nor do they have to change the way they request help. You have absolutely no idea of the OP's background. Perhaps English isn't their first language, and "I want"'s equivalent in their native language just might be an appropriate request for assistance?

Comment: @ItamarG3 don't worry she is beginner, will learn more and will be good, everyone passes by these stage here

Comment: @ItamarG3 even if it was an “appropriate request for assistance”, it still doesn’t make it a problem description.

Comment: @CBroe I'll make my meaning clearer: There was no need for the sarcastic tone in "Did I not just tell you, that...". A bit of patience can help a beginner go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick=" javascript:return abc();" runat="server" />



    <script>
    function abc() {
        debugger;
        var stringVariable = "one,two,three"; // string
        var arrayVariable = stringVariable.split(","); // now string to array
        var arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
        var temp;
        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.className = 'results';
            temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i];
            $('#inputcomshow').append(temp);
            //document.getElementById("#inputcomshow").value = replaced
        }
        return false;
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer can you please do one more answer about this question?  how to add one more <span> with this div

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert string into array first.
Use this:

```
   function abc()
    {
        debugger;
        var stringVariable = "one,two,three"; // string
        var arrayVariable = stringVariable.split(","); // now string to array
        var arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
        var temp;
        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.className = 'results';
            temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i];
            $('#inputcomshow').append(temp);
            //document.getElementById("#inputcomshow").value = replaced
        }
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thankx for help but i i have already try it but the problem is its not stable i mean it shows  when click on button for a second then automatically hide it??

Comment: @aparnarai do you see appended html on page, may be it be hide by some css

Comment: ok so can you please do one more answer about this question? how to add one more <span class=""></span> with this div> like <div  id= "inputcomshow"><div class="results" ><span class="res" >x<span></div></div>

Comment: @aparnarai you can just update as temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i]+'<span class="res" >x</span>';

Answer (score 0):

Try it with less number variable and pure javascript, because you only used single line jQuery code `$('#inputcomshow').append(temp);`.

```
function abc(){
    var arrayVariable = "one,two,three";
    arrayVariable = arrayVariable.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < arrayVariable.length; i++) {
        temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.className = 'results';
        temp.innerHTML = arrayVariable[i];
        document.getElementById("inputcomshow").appendChild(temp);
    }
}
```